# How can I populate a context menu on load?

Tags: c++, windows, explorer, windows-shell

I have items that I want to go into a context menu. The problem is that the items take a while to generate. Therefore, if I have to prepopulate the context menu, i have to populate all 1500 items which takes a while even if those submenu's arent accessed. Therefore, I am looking for a way to populate the menu only if it is actually opened. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You must be kidding? A context menu with 1500 items? You may want to rethink your GUI design before your users flagrantly attack you.

Comment: @AJG85 1500 is the design spec maximum. The average expected is supposed to be about 5. Those 5 though each take about 0.2 seconds to load (because they are the result of a status check on a remote server) so I still need the load on demand.

Comment: I've seen similar context menus, sometimes there's just no way out.. I would suggest to start a helper thread which initializes the menu items. If the context menu is accessed and the menu is not loaded yet the user will just have to wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [IContextMenu2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776091(v=vs.85).aspx) interface sends a [WM_INITMENUPOPUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646347(v=vs.85).aspx) message which allows you to fill in items right before the menu is about to pop up.